# Complex Monge Ampere equal with zero right hand side

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, complex-geometry

Let $(X, \omega)$ be a compact Kaehler manifold, with $K_{X}$ numerically effective. Suppose that $[\zeta] = c_1(K_X)$ and $\int_{X}\zeta^n = 0$. I am interested in solving

\begin{equation}
(\zeta + i \partial \bar \partial f)^n = 0
\end{equation}

for some $f$ smooth. This is immediate if we assume $\zeta \geq 0$. So a solution should be expected to exist by the positivity conjecture in algebraic geometry. But that is certainly a quite hard problem. I wonder whether there has been any results/progresses on solving such an equation.